# Should we differentiate 'echoed' request fields in a POST response?

Tags: api, naming-conventions

The web application we are developing allows developers to do an HTTP POST from a form (that they develop) to our servers. We provide them with an API reference for the request and response field names.

One particular requirement of our application is that the response must include all request fields that were originally submitted - kind of like an echo of the request fields in the response.

To try and keep the API **intuitive** and **unambiguous**, I have suggested that in the response field names, we prepend those 'echoed' request fields with something (e.g. 'req_' or 'request_') to differentiate them from true response data. However, a few of the guys are not so sure with this approach, and they suggest that we just keep the names the same.

I would appreciate your opinions on this; I'm relatively new to defining APIs so any feedback would be great.

To summarize, the two options on the table are:

## Option 1 - Don't Differentiate Request Fields In Response

**request:**

```
name: 'Joe Bloggs'
address: '22 My Street, My City'
amount: '100.00'
```

**response:**

```
transaction_id: '384765'
transaction_time: '2011-12-31T11:59:59Z'
message: 'Your transaction was successful.'
name: 'Joe Bloggs'
address: '22 My Street, My City'
amount: '100.00'
```

## Option 2 - Differentiate Request Fields In Response

**request:**

```
name: 'Joe Bloggs'
address: '22 My Street, My City'
amount: '100.00'
```

**response:**

```
transaction_id: '384765'
transaction_time: '2011-12-31T11:59:59Z'
message: 'Your transaction was successful.'
req_name: 'Joe Bloggs'
req_address: '22 My Street, My City'
req_amount: '100.00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would not differentiate the request fields as it could get confusing for the developer, it would also require you to have a correct naming convention so that your field names do not clash.

Comment: Ok, I was thinking that it would be less confusing for them i.e. we document that any 'req_' fields are simply those fields that were submitted in the request. But maybe I'm totally wrong here...

Comment: you could always prefix your initial fields with `req_`, and then respond with `req_`, but the whole reason for an API is to give access to your data with minimal overhead, for example `req_` is only 4 extra chars, this may not seem like much but times that by 10 fields thats 40 extra chars, once again that may not be too much, but if you had lets say 1000 clients using the API thats 40,000 extra chars, then each of those clients make an average of 1000 requests per day you end up wht 40,000,000 extra chars that are not really required, just something worth thinking about aswell :)